# Как Загрузить случайный рисунок из ресурса

Tags: android, java

Как Загрузить случайный рисунок из ресурса

Bitmap b = null; 
b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),**R.drawable.icon)**;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел ответ

```
final int[] cardDeck = new int[] {R.drawable.1,  R.drawable.2}; 
b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), cardDeck[i]);
```